# Creating LKM using Makefile

Tags: linux-kernel, freebsd, kernel-modules, make, c

As of lately, I have decided to begin learning about OS kernels and came across a few resources to aid in my learning process. Following the tutorial, I setup an Loadable Kernel Module  and Makefile, yet when I run the `make`command I get the following command:
`Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Makefile contents-

```
KMOD=   hello   #Name of KLD build.
SRCS=   hello.c # List of source files.
include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

LKM source-

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>

/*The function called at load/unload. */
static int
load(struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg)
{
    int error = 0;

    switch (cmd) {
    case MOD_LOAD:
        uprintf("Hello, world!\n");
        break;
        
    case MOD_UNLOAD:
        uprintf("Good-bye, cruel world!\n");
        break;
        
    default:
        error = EOPNOTSUPP;
        break;
    }
}

/* The second argument of DECLARE_MODULE. */
static moduledata_t hello_mod = {
    "hello",    /*module name */
    load,       /* event handler */
    NULL        /* extra data */
};

DECLARE_MODULE(hello, hello_mod, SI_SUB_DRIVERS, SI_ORDER_MIDDLE);
```

The book that I am following along with focuses on FreeBSD kernel modules, and I am porting this over to my Ubuntu system to alter the kernel.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

> The book that I am following along with focuses on FreeBSD kernel modules, and I am porting this over to my Ubuntu system to alter the kernel.

That’s unlikely to produce useful results any time soon because the two kernels are very different, as are their build infrastructures. Instead, follow a Linux-specific tutorial, e.g. [this one](https://blog.sourcerer.io/writing-a-simple-linux-kernel-module-d9dc3762c234).